# Materialize - disable form styling

Tags: css, materialize

Is possible to change default materialize form styling? For instance remove underline from focused input.

[materialize framework link](http://materializecss.com/forms.html)

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the CSS rules or the JS animations too?

Comment: I think both. For instance I want to have simple html input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overwriting the CSS styles is easy: you create a custom CSS stylesheet and include that **after** the materialize CSS stylesheet. Then you find out what rules are set by Materialize, and overwrite them.

For example, the border below the input-fields, are styled by MaterializeCSS like this:

```
input:not([type]), input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email], input[type=url], input[type=time], input[type=date], input[type=datetime], input[type=datetime-local], input[type=tel], input[type=number], input[type=search], textarea.materialize-textarea {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
    border-radius: 0;
    outline: none;
    height: 3rem;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

To remove the `border-bottom`, in your custom CSS sheet you set this rule:

```
input:not([type]), input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email], input[type=url], input[type=time], input[type=date], input[type=datetime], input[type=datetime-local], input[type=tel], input[type=number], input[type=search], textarea.materialize-textarea {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Disabling the JS functions is harder, you would have to change the source JS code for that and remove functions you don't like.

Comment: curious: what's the "input:not([type])" for?

Comment: @SyberKnight This answer is four years old so I'm not 100% sure but I assume the above code was copied from MaterializeCSS in their source. It may have changed. The answer to your question is that it would style every input field that doesn't have a type set to it. So <input /> would be targetted. This only makes sense for hidden fields I think as you would probably use a type on visible fields at all times. The css framework was in alpha phase back then and might have done it for other reasons such as cross-browser inconsistent styling.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using Sass you can import a new scss file after the materialize css implementation (http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html)

This can with NPM or Bower. There is also a Rails Gem (https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass)

Answer (score 0):

Materialize also allows you to add a browser-default class if all you want is the simple html input as you say